# Query on an array of documents with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with two documents:

```
{
    "type":"s",
    "disp":[
        {
            "quantity":1,
            "date":20141109
        },
        {
            "quantity":1,
            "date":20141110
        }
    ]
},
{
    "type":"d",
    "disp":[
        {
            "quantity":1,
            "date":20141109
        },
        {
            "quantity":0,
            "date":20141110
        }
    ]
}
```

I have to make a query (with one or more dates) to retrieve a document where all the given dates have a quantity greater than 0.

So if I search for a date 20141109 then I have to retrieve both but searching for 20141110 or both dates 20141109 and 20141110 should return only type "s" as it's the only with a quantity bigger than 0 for every dates used as parameters

P.S. sorry for my English, it's not my first language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do such a match for one date, use `$elemMatch`:

```
db.test.find({ "disp" : { "$elemMatch" : { "quantity" : { "$gt" : 0 }, "date" : 20141109} } })
```

For multiple dates you will need to combine queries like the above using `$and`:

```
db.test.find({ "$and" : [
    { "disp" : { "$elemMatch" : { "quantity" : { "$gt" : 0 }, "date" : 20141109 } } },
    { "disp" : { "$elemMatch" : { "quantity" : { "$gt" : 0 }, "date" : 20141110 } } }
] })
```

Comment: I just wonder if there's a way to get only the "disp" elements matched